# Try statements acting up in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to figure out try statements in AppleScript. I got it to compile, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
try
do shell script "cat " & passData
on error

display dialog "Create a password to protect this file. After creating the password, you will need to enter it every time in order to access the app." default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 with hidden answer
set pass1 to text returned of result
display dialog "Confirm the password you entered." default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 with hidden answer
set pass2 to text returned of result

if pass1 is pass2 then
    set setPass to pass2
    set passSalt to random number from 10000000 to 99999999
    do shell script "echo " & setPass & " | shasum -a 512 | awk '{print $1}'"
    set passHash to result
    set cHash1 to random number from 10 to 25
    set cHash2 to random number from 26 to 50
    set cHash3 to random number from 51 to 75
    set cHash4 to random number from 76 to 99
    set hBlock1 to characters cHash1 through cHash2 of passHash
    set hBlock2 to characters cHash3 through cHash4 of passHash
    set finalHash to hBlock1 & passHash & hBlock2
    do shell script "echo " & passSalt & return & cHash1 & return & cHash2 & return & cHash3 & return & cHash4 & " > " & passData
    do shell script "echo " & finalHash & " > " & appPath & "Contents/Resources/FinalHash.txt"

else
    display dialog "The passwords didn't match. Restart the application and try again." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    quit
end if
quit
end try
```

I want the application to quit if the text entered in the first and second dialog boxes don't match, but it just goes on to the rest of the code. I also want the application to quit after it does all the hashing mumbo jumbo if the text entered in the boxes match, but it doesn't do that either. How can I fix this? I suspect it has something to do with the *try* statements.

Edit: when I said it goes on to the rest of the code, I meant when I exported it as an app. It works correctly in the editor but in the app it continues to the rest of the code.

Comment: Hint: In Script-Editor, Ctrl-Click into a script to see code-snippets. it has also some for error handling (try blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found out a way that works! :)

Between the **try** and **on error**, I added *set quitFunction to "0"*. Then between the **on error** and **end try** I added *set quitFunction to 1*. After the **end try** I made the script test if the variable quitFunction is 1. If it is, it quits and if it isn't, it doesn't quit.

Answer (score 0):

You put an `end try` on the end of your script, but there's no opening `try` to close off.

In the code below I've removed the `end try`. In addition to that, I've added `tell application "finder"` and `end tell` to prevent your script editor from quiting.

Tried it and it works fine here.

```
tell application "Finder"
    display dialog "Create a password to protect this file. After creating the password, you will need to enter it every time in order to access the app." default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 with hidden answer
    set pass1 to text returned of result
    display dialog "Confirm the password you entered." default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 with hidden answer
    set pass2 to text returned of result

if pass1 is pass2 then
    set setPass to pass2
    set passSalt to random number from 10000000 to 99999999
    do shell script "echo " & setPass & " | shasum -a 512 | awk '{print $1}'"
    set passHash to result
    set cHash1 to random number from 10 to 25
    set cHash2 to random number from 26 to 50
    set cHash3 to random number from 51 to 75
    set cHash4 to random number from 76 to 99
    set hBlock1 to characters cHash1 through cHash2 of passHash
    set hBlock2 to characters cHash3 through cHash4 of passHash
    set finalHash to hBlock1 & passHash & hBlock2
    do shell script "echo " & passSalt & return & cHash1 & return & cHash2 & return & cHash3 & return & cHash4 & " > " & passData
    do shell script "echo " & finalHash & " > " & appPath & "Contents/Resources/FinalHash.txt"
else
    display dialog "The passwords didn't match. Restart the application and try again." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    quit
end if
end tell
```

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally left out the _try_ at the top of my script. And sorry if I was being unclear, but I want the app to close if the two passwords don't match. I also want it to close after doing the hashing stuff. It closes when I'm in the editor, but not in the app which is weird. In the app, it continues to the rest of the script, prompting you to enter a password if the passwords don't match. It doesn't do this in the editor though.

Comment: What app do you mean? Do you have the entire app in apple script?

Comment: I exported the script as an application, and that's where it starts acting up. It works as I want it to in the editor.

Comment: I've tried it and it works here. How did you export it? From which application and with what kind of settings?